# two tab bar items working with one viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a tabbarcontroller in xcode 4.5 with five view controllers (5 items), and I want item 2 don't show its view controller, but I want to show (when is marked) various GMSMarker in View controller number 3, and hide these markers (when tabbaritem is not marked). The viewController 3 is showing a GoogleMap.

I am a beginner, and i've tried the function "setSelectedIndex", but it doesn`t work to me.

Have anyone any ideas??

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITabBarController` is designed to hold separate `UIViewController` instances for each tab. A better way to achieve what I think you are trying to do is simply create more than one instance of the `UIViewController` you are trying to use in items 2 and 3. If that isn't possible, you may be planning out a bad UX (and you could consider combining the two tabs into just one, and putting a segmented control or something inside  of there to toggle functionality).